# How to add to VSC intellisense javascript modules?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on backbone projects and using the `define` method to créate modules for the Project, and also all the projects are node apps.
This is an example of a simple module that only contains a simple object.

```
define("UAStrings", [], function() {
  var UAStrings = {
    Screensaver: "Screensaver",
    ScreensaverOff: "ScreensaverOff",
    Home: "Home",
    Plan: "Plan",
    Destination: "Destination",
    ComingSoon: "ComingSoon",
    Services: "Services",
    StoresAZ: "Screen Destinations A - Z" ,
    Themes: "Screen Destinations Themes",
    Restaurants: "Sreen Restaurants",
    Promotions: "Promotions",
  };

  return UAStrings;
});
```

In VSC intellisense does not bring me the atributes of the UAStrings object, and this happens to all my JS files, there is no connection for intellisense.

Could you hep me?

This is my actual `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "amd"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/js/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You could download another intellisense plugin and peek at its source.

Comment: Like what other plugin, intellisense is part of VSC

Comment: Then what are all these other intellisense plugins?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, do you have a plugin that can solve my issue?